# Creating Installshield Prerequisite for both 32bit and 64bit

Tags: 32bit-64bit, installshield, setup-project, prerequisites

I'm in the process of adding MySQL ODBC conector as a prerequisite in Installshield. Oracle provides two separate MSI for 32bit and 64bit and they dont support cross-architecture(32-64).

I'm able to add both of these modules as two separate prerequisite with two separate custom conditions to check for the exact architecture.(win32 or win64)

when I used both of these prerequisite in a setup project I'm not able to build it for 32 bit. If I build it for 64 bit the setup will support only for 64 bit PCs.

Is there any option to add both 32bit and 64 bit prerequisites to a single setup and make it run on both platforms and let it to decide to install the suitable version of the prerequisite.

prerequisite conditions are as below

```
User is running a particular OS -> Custom(Platform Id=Any, Major Version=10,Minor Version1, Service Packs=-,Product Type=Any, Platform Architecture=Win32, CSDVersion="", Build No=)

User is running a particular OS -> Custom(Platform Id=Any, Major Version=10,Minor Version1, Service Packs=-,Product Type=Any, Platform Architecture=Win64, CSDVersion="", Build No=)
```

PS- I'm using Installshield 2015 premier edition (SP1) with VS2013

The error msg when I tried to build it or 32bit is:

```
error -5008: intel64 or amd64 must be specified in the template of the summary
```

Comment: You should be able to include two prerequisites as you described without having to target 64-bit systems. Can you clarify what version and edition of InstallShield you're using, as well as what project type? What error do you get when you tried to include both and build for 32-bit?

Comment: @michael post updated

Comment: I'm not in a good position to verify the 5008 error is what I think, but if it is, it's from 64-bit components or files in your project itself, and has nothing to do with your prerequisites. Do you get the same error if you deselect the prerequisites? If so, resolve that separately, and your prerequisites should be fine.

Comment: "when I used both of these prerequisite in a setup project I'm not able to build it for 32 bit. If I build it for 64 bit the setup will support only for 64 bit PCs."

Comment: So if you create a new basic MSI project and add one file and those prerequisites, you get the same error?

Comment: Just basic question here @Kuma : So you want only one installer that works on both 32 & 64 bit OS. IS my my understanding is correct ? 
And as Michael said, if its having any 64 bit component marked, then it wont work for 32 bit system. 
For that you can add two Releases under Release tab and there you can create 32 bit and 64 bit entries for separate builds.

Answer (score 1):

In the General Information view, Summary Information Stream section, set the Template Summary property to x64;1033. Note: If you live in a country where English is not the language, you will use a different language code from 1033.

This will make sure your installation if  64bit. In a 64bit installer, you can add 32bit components.

Comment: with this setting will the installer run on a 32bit system ?

Comment: No. With this setting, installer wont work on 32 bit system.